# Why have my itemize environments been corrupted and how can I fix the issue?

Tags: spacing, lists

I am using the `ut-thesis` template, and this is what stock bulleted lists look like:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}

 %...

\begin{itemize}
\item{I like margin}
\item{I like margarine}
\end{itemize}

\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0pt]
\item{I don't like}
\item{I don't like margarine}
\end{itemize}
```

[image]

But now in my document, for some reason, the lists have started to look like this:

[image]

with massive space between them.  I am using the \usepackage{enumitem} declaration

Why are my lists so spacey now?  Using Bakoma Tex 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Oh, I understand**.

It's just a property of how LaTeX decided to flow my document.  Because I had an image placed with `[H]` immediately below the bullet list, it decided to add massive space to the bulleted lists, as a sort of filler (because the image wouldn't fit on the page and had to go on the next page).  I had never encountered this type of "vertical justification" before, while it's pretty neat, it's pretty disorienting too.

To override this behaviour, I can add arguments to itemize to make it work:

```
\begin{itemize}\itemsep0pt \parskip0pt \parsep0pt
\item{I like margin}
\item{I like margarine}
\end{itemize}
```

This gives a list with no extra spacing.

**but** there is a lot of empty space around the list now, so you're probably better off letting LaTeX do it's flow thang (in this case I just took the `[H]` off).

Comment: A cool trick is to use the *placeins* package. This enables you to use the restrict where figures,tables and such can float.

Comment: The fundamental error is to use the `[H]` specifier. Don't.

Comment: Sometimes I `[H]`ave to